Tried using Sublime to help build my sitemap
I just wanted to build a sitemap for my website, and one search said that I should use Sublime to turn my URLs into XML or to add XML codes to my URLs.
I'm either on drugs, a moron, or both. I thought that downloading the best sublime download, putting in my URLs, and pushing a button to change to XML would've helped me to create a sitemap.
OH HELL NO
First of all, it looked like there were about 500 different Sublime downloads. I chose the one that was underlined. Something like 64 bit for windows.
I was able to key in my URLs, but then I might just well as turned off my computer because I was lost.
Maybe if I start taking drugs, then I'll see the light.
Any suggestions?

use online tool for that https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/
